# "this is null" when change in v-select [NuxtJs]

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

this is my first post! Hope you can help.
So I'm on some new project to migrate to nuxtJs.

I have some trouble with my v-select and v-model, here's the code:

**_id.vue:**

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid white>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title class="headline">
          TEST:
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <p>info :</p>
        <p>{{this.host.typeS}}</p>
        <v-select 
          v-model="this.host.typeS" 
          :items="this.fields.typeS" 
          item-value="value"   
          item-text="value" 
          dense outlined>
        </v-select>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

**script**

```js
export default {
  name: 'EditPage',
  data() {
    return {
      tab: null,
      fields: [],
      host: {},
      tabHeaders: ["tab1", "tab2", "tab3", "tab4", "tab5", "tab6"]
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    this.fields = await fetch("APIfields")
      .then(res => res.json());
    if (this.$nuxt._route.params.id) {
      this.host = await fetch("APIhost" + this.$nuxt._route.params.id).then(res => res.json());
    } else {
      this.host = {};
    }
  }
}
```

**responses**

APIfields:

```json
{"typeS": [{"value": "p","order": 100}, {"value":"v","order": 100}], 
      "otherThings": [{"value":"se", "order": 100},{"value":"sa", "order": 100}]}
```

APIhost/id:

```json
{"typeS": "p", 
  "otherThings": "se"}
```

When everything run, My select is initiated with the value "p" and when clicked I see all the values this field can have.
When I try selecting "v" in the v-select, I'm redirected to my error layout, and the console say "Type error: this is null".

Without the v-model, I don't have any error, but the v-select have no selected value.

The goal is to initialise a form based on an existing host, change the data inside the form and then submit it to the database. The form should also be used to create new hosts (empty form)

The same error appear in my textfields and checkboxes.

Do you have any idea or track I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need `this` when working on vue templates

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid white>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title class="headline">
          TEST:
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <p>info :</p>
        <p>{{host.typeS}}</p>
        <v-select 
          v-model="host.typeS" 
          :items="fields.typeS" 
          item-value="value"   
          item-text="value" 
          dense outlined>
        </v-select>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

note that `:items` takes an array but you are using `fields.typeS` so it's better to set field in data as

```js
fields: {}
```

since it's an object

Comment: Thanks, I thought since the fields.typeS returned an array of objects, it was an array instead of an object containing multiple objects. Here in my exemple I only have 2 values for typeS, but some other fields I'm working with have 10 or more different values.
I can't try right now, but I'll be sure to come back to you after trying this out without "this."

Comment: Ok so it worked great, thank you for your answer!

If I can ask: I don't need "this" in the vue template, but with it the correct values were found anyway (the v-select had the correct values in), do why don't "this" worked exactly? I'm learning so it may be an obvious reason, but I don't understand why I couldn't change my values before applying your correction.

Comment: @shilvor I'm not 100% sure, but I think that vue is removing the extra `this` you had for the `:items` since it's a bind object, but for the v-model it fails when it tries to write to the property in the object. generally you should not use `this` in templates. Also if this answered your question then consider choosing it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark under the voting buttons